# Covariance function in R for covariance matrix of residuals

Tags: r, covariance

I am looking for a function in R to calculate the covariance matrix of the residuals of an OLS regression. I am unable to find if the `cov()` function takes into account degrees of freedom of the model and the number of data points in the model when it computes the covariance matrix.

Update: I am trying to do an optimization process that minimizes the residuals of an OLS regression. Typically the unbiased OLS residual variance is given by : E(RSS/N−p-1)=σ². Where RSS is the Residual Sum of Squares, N the number of observations and p the number of coefficients. I am trying to see if such a correction is needed for computing the covariance matrix and if so, is there a function in R that does it?

Comment: the residual of an LR model is a vector and covariance matrix is just single scaler. Maybe you are looking for something else

Comment: following up on @Reza's comment; the residuals of an OLS are typically **assumed** to be independent and homoscedastic, so `diag(rep(sigma(model)^2,nobs(model)))` would (sort of trivially) be the answer.  Can you be more specific/give more context for the problem you're trying to solve?  Or are you talking about the estimated covariance matrix of the sampling distribution of the *parameters*, i.e. `vcov()` ?

Comment: You can try posting your update as a question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vcov()` function with the summary object after running a regression using the `lm` function.

Here's an example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
 vcov(summary(lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + cyl + carb, data = mtcars)))

            (Intercept)          disp          wt          cyl        carb
(Intercept)  8.55669203  0.0293259201 -2.08615285 -1.491482503  0.29243798
disp         0.02932592  0.0001528819 -0.00919016 -0.006308583  0.00142303
wt          -2.08615285 -0.0091901600  1.12326190  0.137990642 -0.09283828
cyl         -1.49148250 -0.0063085825  0.13799064  0.454163264 -0.10918226
carb         0.29243798  0.0014230298 -0.09283828 -0.109182256  0.12568429
```

This is another way of writing the syntax:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + cyl + carb, data = mtcars)

modelsum <- summary(model)

vcov(modelsum)
```

Comment: this is the covariance of the regression coefficients